# Why do earthworms have 4 hearts?

Tags: cardiology, circulatory-system

I was reading about earthworms and came to know that they have 4 hearts.

Why is there a need for a 4 heart system? What advantages would it have over a 1 heart circulatory system except for pumping more blood obviously.

Comment: The earthworm heart is not really like a vertebrate heart. They are not that efficient. More like valves you can say.

Comment: "*pumping more blood obviously*" Is it obvious? To me it is more obvious that there are way more factors in blood flow than the number of hearts. An interesting factoid though, I didn't know about this! You learn something new everyday they say, thanks.

Comment: Today suddenly many people are concern about heart :P